# WIF, ADFS 2.0, wsignoutcleanup1.0 and wreply

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, wif, adfs2.0, ws-federation

I have set up a WIF web application, a custom STS and an ADFS 2.0 instance as the go between. I am having a hard time understanding the sign out process for my application. Currently, when my user clicks the sign out button, I am calling this code:

```
WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(null, new Uri("https://myrelyingpartyapp.com/?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0"));
```

If I use this code, it works fine. All of the cookies and sessions are disposed of correctly. The only problem is that the browser just displays a little green check after the process is over. Obviously, I want to be redirected back to the login page of the STS. To accomplish this I attempted the following code:

```
WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(null, new Uri("https://myrelyingpartyapp.com/?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0&wreply=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://myrelyingpartyapp.com/Default.aspx")));
```

My belief was that the wreply would cause the user to be redirected back to my relying party app where they would be unauthorized and therefore be redirected back to the STS login page. Instead this causes an error in ADFS (which I cannot see because of their helpful error page.) No matter what url I use for wreply, the error is thrown. **Am I using wsignoutcleanup1.0 correctly?** Just for reference, here is the code in my STS where I handle sign in/sign out requests:

```
if (action == "wsignin1.0")
{
  SignInRequestMessage signInRequestMessage = (SignInRequestMessage)WSFederationMessage.CreateFromUri(Request.Url);

  if (User != null && User.Identity != null && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
  {
    SecurityTokenService securityTokenService = new CustomSecurityTokenService(CustomSecurityTokenServiceConfiguration.Current);
    SignInResponseMessage signInResponseMessage = FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations.ProcessSignInRequest(signInRequestMessage, User as ClaimsPrincipal, securityTokenService);
    FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations.ProcessSignInResponse(signInResponseMessage, Response);
  }
  else
  {
     throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
  }
}
else if (action == "wsignout1.0")
{
  SignOutRequestMessage signOutRequestMessage = (SignOutRequestMessage)WSFederationMessage.CreateFromUri(Request.Url);                    
  FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations.ProcessSignOutRequest(signOutRequestMessage, User as ClaimsPrincipal, signOutRequestMessage.Reply, Response);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed for correct behavior was correct logout code. This code eventually logged my user out and did a proper cleanup:

```
var module = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
module.SignOut(false);
var request = new SignOutRequestMessage(new Uri(module.Issuer), module.Realm);
Response.Redirect(request.WriteQueryString());
```

This code was put in the event handler of my logout button on my relying party app.